# How to mock App::make() on UnitTesting Laravel 4

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, laravel-4

i got a question when i was unit testing my application. I Have a method that require a dependency but only that method need it so i thought to don't inject it by construct but initialize it with App::make() of the IoC container Class. But now how can i unit test that?

Let's say a short example for understand how you unit testing this function of example

```
class Example {

  public function methodToTest()
  {
       $dependency = App::make('Dependency');
       return $dependency->method('toTest');
  }

}
```

Test

```
public function test_MethodToTest() {
  $dependency =  m::mock('Dependency');
  $dependency->shouldReceive('method')->once()->with('toTest')->andReturn(true);

  $class = new Example();
  $this->assertTrue($class->methodToTest('toTest')); // does not work
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're almost there. Create an anonymous mock with the expectations that you need and then register that mock as the instance for Dependency and you should be good to go.

That would look something like this

```
public function test_MethodToTest() {
    $dependency =  m::mock();
    $dependency->shouldReceive('method')->once()->with('toTest')->andReturn(true);
    App::instance('Dependancy', $dependancy);

    $class = new Example();
    $this->assertTrue($class->methodToTest()); // should work
}
```

Comment: It works, but with getMock() `$dependency->getMock()`

Comment: No. If you use $dependency->getMock() directly you're only testing that the mock has been set up correctly, not that the Example class's methodToTest() is called as expected. If $class->methodToTest() didn't work for you, I recommend looking at the way your equivalent of the Example class has been setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to inject the dependency in `Example` classes constructor.

```
class Example{
    /** @var Dependency */
    private $dependency;

    public function __construct(Dependency $dependency){
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }

    public function methodToTest(){
        return $this->dependency->method('toTest');
    }
}

class Test{
    public function test_MethodToTest(){
        $mock = Mockery::mock(Dependency::class);
        $mock->shouldReceive('method')->once()->with('toTest')->andReturn(true);

        $class = new Example($mock);
        $this->assertTrue($class->methodToTest());
    }
}
```

In your controller, libraries you can then use IoC like this

```
$example = App::make(Example::class);
```